# Найти отличия в строках на PHP

Tags: php

Есть две строки

```
$str_1 = 'Привет, Вова';
$str_2 = 'Привет, Андрей';
```

Каким способом можно сравнить две строки, чтобы найти отличие второй строки от первой. Т.е. в результате получится следующая строка:

```
$str_3 = 'Андрей';
```

Comment: Что такое `отличие`? Если первая строка будет `$str_1 = 'Привет, Вова, Андрей';` что должно получиться в итоге?

Comment: я так понял `diff` нужен

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, понравилось, как здесь на сайте реализована история правок. Вот и пытаюсь реализовать подобное на php и mysql

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос что такое "отличие".

Comment: 90% всей работы программиста уже было сделано за него, не стоит писать велосипеды :) https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff

Answer (score 0):

Можно вариант через exec

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/tmp1', 'Привет, Вова');
file_put_contents('/tmp/tmp2', 'Привет, Петя');

$output = [];
exec('diff -c /tmp/tmp1 /tmp/tmp2', $output);

var_dump($output);
```